# apply-templates not picking up new attributes

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-2.0

I have the following templates in my XSLT file:

```
<xsl:template match="ns1:SUBJECT" mode="doc_copy">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:if test="$subjectHasClass eq false()">
      <xsl:attribute name="ns2:class" select="$class"/>
    </xsl:if>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="@ns2:class[contains(., 'R')]">
  <xsl:choose>
    <xsl:when test="$owner ne 'U'">
      <xsl:attribute name="ns2:class" select="'R'"/>
    </xsl:when>
    <xsl:otherwise>
      <xsl:attribute name="ns2:class" select="'C'"/>
    </xsl:otherwise>
  </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>
```

In this case, assume `$subjectHasClass` is `false`, `$class` is `"R"` and `$owner` is `"U"`. Here's the relevant tag in my XML:

```
<ns1:SUBJECT>Title of document</SUBJECT>
```

The problem I'm having is that I want the `apply-templates` in the first template to pick up the new attribute I've added and run the second template on them. I assume the fact that it only picks up pre-existing attributes is by design but I'm curious if there's a way around that limitation or a better design pattern to use here.

Comment: What version and processor are you using? My guess is there might be a way if you use XSLT 2.0 or `exslt:node-set` in XSLT 1.0. Or you just need to run a second XSLT over it after you create the first with the attributes.

Comment: To clarify why `apply-templates` isn't picking up on the attribute you're creating, `<xsl:attribute name="ns2:class" select="$class"/>` sends an attribute to the _output_, whereas `<xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>` will (in typical cases) operate on the _input_.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@MatthewGreen's comment led me down the path to an answer. I looked up ways to do multipass processing in XSLT 2.0 and came up with this.

```
<xsl:template match="ns1:SUBJECT" mode="doc_copy">
  <xsl:variable name="subj-attrs">
    <temp>
      <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="$subjectHasClass=false()">
          <xsl:attribute name="ns2:class" select="$class"/>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
          <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>
        </xsl:otherwise>
      </xsl:choose>
    </temp>
  </xsl:variable>
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="$subj-attrs/temp/@*"/>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="node()"/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

It processes the attributes (new or existing) into a temporary node and stores it in a variable, then we apply our templates to that variable.